# Nodemailer: Connection Timeout error when password string contains '#'

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I have an application in nodejs which uses nodemailer to send emails. Everything works fine except when the password string contains '#' in it.

Below is my code

```
var secure = config.secure ? "smtps":"smtp";
var conURL = secure+"://"+config.user+":"+config.pass+"@"+config.host+"/?pool=false";

try {
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport(conURL);

    // verify connection configuration
    transport.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.message) // Error : Connection Timeout
    }
});
```

When the password contains '#' character, I am getting an Connection Timeout error. I have tested with @, !, $ etc all working fine.

Can someone help on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to encode the URI

So, something like this should do the trick I suppose

```
secure+"://"+config.user+":"+encodeURIComponent(config.pass)+"@"+config.host+"/?pool=false"
```

EDIT: Try using a config object instead of a URI like this

```
const config = {
    pool: false,
    host: config.host,
    secure: config.secure,
    auth: {
        user: config.user,
        pass: config.pass
    }
};

try {
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport(conURL);

    // verify connection configuration
    transport.verify(function(error, success) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.message) // Error : Connection Timeout
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems working when I encode only the password field.  I will update after testing with some other special characters also

Comment: Oops... Actually that's correct. My bad. You just have to use encodeURIComponent only on the password.

Comment: Did either of the solutions help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182622/discussion-between-pramodh-valavala-and-vineesh).